# DataTables initialization using html attribute

Tags: html, datatables

I have table

```
<table class="table dataTable table-striped table-bordered" 
           cellspacing="0" width="100%"
           data-toggle="table"
           data-processing="true"
           data-serverSide="true"
           data-ajax="@Url.Action("GetUsers", "Users")"
           data-type="post"
           data-page-length="25" 
           data-order="[[0,&quot;asc&quot;]]"
           >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Role</th>
                <th>User name</th>
                <th>Date registered</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

my js where init table

```
$(document).ready(() => {
let table = $('[data-toggle="table"]');
if (table.length > 1) {
    table.DataTable();
}
```

});

I sees request ajax to GetUsers, but without parameters. What I should to do for fixed it? I should using more html attributes, or I should using js?

Comment: where is your javascript code?

Comment: add body of js file